# Xcode6 Interface Builder has "hidden" my views?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

[image: screnshot]

[image: close up of icons]

I am not sure how this happened but the view hierarchy on my Xcode6 project have 'hidden' themselves.

On the menu on the left the views have a weird icon and on the layout view and on the app itself the views do not appear.

On the right side all the constraints are greyed out.

Is this a feature or a bug? i can't really find anything i can click to get them to show again. Did i accidentally hit a shortcut?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think you have changed the `size class` in the Xcode. May be you have designed it in one size class(not in `wAny hAny`)and accidentally changed to another. Only the layout designed in `wAny hAny` will be available for all devices/orientations. If you chosen any specific size class,  your view's and constraint's will be hidden for other layouts(grey out). To get it back change size class at the bottom of the IB to yours(i don't know which one you have chosen initially). I would suggest you to design your layout in `wAny hAny` and do any specific layout changes for a device/orientation using other size classes.

change it here **wAny hAny** (Interface builder bottom)
[image]